# Are there infinite elements in the super prime set?

Tags: probability-distributions, prime-numbers

### Background

Define the following set, the initial elements are $\{2,3,5,7\}$.

Then, repeat the following operations, if you add a digit to any position of any number in the set, the number is still a prime number, then add the new number to the set.

For example, add a digit in front of $3$, $\{31, 37\}$ is still a prime number, so add the set.

Add a digit after $3$, $\{13,23,43,53,73,83\}$ is still a prime number, and it is also added to the set.

Name this set as the **Super Prime Set** in base 10.

The question is, how many elements does this set have, is it infinite?

---

### Some Attempts

From the distribution point of view, the prime number will be more and more coefficients, until it crosses a gap that enlarge 10 times and still cannot find a prime number.

But on the other hand there must be at least one prime number between $[n, 10n]$, then we can try $\log_{10}(n)$ times of insertion, and any number that is a prime number can make the collection continue to grow, which may make this set grow infinitely.

I'm not sure about the exact situation in base 10.

I tried breadth-first search and after a few iterations I ran out of memory.

I switched to depth-first search and find a 1000 elements loog super prime chain and still seem to be able to grow.

This is my search path:
[prime2.py](https://github.com/oovm/fun-numbers/blob/dev/projects/super-prime/tests/prime2.py), A larger search is beyond my computing power.

### Additional Questions

If there is a maximum value, is there a way to quickly estimate the largest number in this set, or the total number of elements in the set?

Comment: FYI: When appending digits exclusively to the head of the numbers, or exclusively to the tail of the numbers, these are the left- and right-[truncatable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime). The $4260$ left-truncatables are sequence [A024785](https://oeis.org/A024785) in OEIS; the $83$ right-truncatables are [A024770](https://oeis.org/A024770).

Comment: @AgnibhoDutta I do not understand your editing of  $(n,10n]\mapsto [n, 10n]$. Do you have a specific reason in mind why $(n, 10n]$ doesn't work but $[n, 10n]$ does?

Answer (score 2):

### Claim

This is not a proof, but I have some heuristic 'evidence' that your Super Prime Set is most likely infinite.

### Argument

Let $I_1 = [2,3,5,7]$ be the initial set.

For the next set, $I_2$, we consider each integer $n$ from $I_1$ and we look if any of the numbers $(d_1 \; n \; d_2)$ in base $10$ are prime, where $d_1$ and $d_2$ are decimal digits, i.e. $d_1, d_2 \in \{0,1, \dots 9\}$.
We therefore look at $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 10 = 80$ possible candidates for our set $I_2$.
Using the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), we can expect that about $80/\ln(10^2) = 40/\ln(10) \approx 17$ of those $80$ candidates are actually prime. This does assume that the set of candidates is sufficiently random.

Now, for $I_3$, we have approximately $17 \cdot 3 \cdot 10 = 510$ candidates.
Again, using the prime number theorem, we expect about $510/\ln(10^3) \approx 74$ primes.

More generally, for $I_n$, we expect to find roughly
$$ \#I_{n-1} \cdot n \cdot 10 / \ln(10^n) = \#I_{n-1} \cdot 10 / \ln(10) \approx \#I_{n-1} \cdot 4.34 $$
primes.
Hence, we get the approximation: $\#I_n \approx (4.34)^{n-1} \cdot 4 \approx (4.34)^n$.

This suggests that the set $I_n$ keeps growing (with an exponential rate even), therefore the Super Prime Set is most likely infinite.

### Python code

The following code constructs the sets $I_n$ and also computes the approximation from above. We see that the actual sets $I_n$ grow even faster than the approximation.
One possible reason for this is that that most of the candidates for $I_n$ are only of size roughly $5 \cdot 10^{n-1}$ instead of $10^n$, improving the number of primes we expect from the prime number theorem.
Another possible reason is that the set of candidates is not completely random, since if we don't alter the last digit of a prime in $I_{n-1}$, then the final digit won't be a $0,2,4,6$ or $8$ (unless we started with the prime $2$).

```
import math as m
from sympy import *

I_old = {2,3,5,7}
I_new = set(I_old)
approx_sum = 4

for i in range(1,8):
    for n in I_old:
        string = str(n)
        if len(string) != i:
            continue
        for d in range(10):
            d_string = str(d)
            for j in range(len(string)):
                new_string = string[:j] + d_string + string[j:]
                new_n = int(new_string)
                if isprime(new_n):
                    I_new.add(new_n)
    I_old = set(I_new)
    approx_sum += 4*(4.34)**(i)
    print(i, len(I_new), round(4*(4.34)**(i)), round(approx_sum))
```

Which gives the following output, where we see that the set grows even faster than the exponential approximation:

```
1 15 17 21
2 77 75 97
3 418 327 424
4 2499 1419 1843
5 16021 6159 8002
6 108447 26730 34732
7 765014 116008 150740
```

---

### Update

Out of curiosity, I wanted to see what happens if we consider the following variation of the Super Prime Set: only allow adding digits to the front and to the back, instead of all possible places.
This means that the sets $I_1$ and $I_2$ will as before, but $I_3$ will be smaller. For example, 151 is now no longer part of $I_3$.

When we work out the heuristic formula for $I_n$ again, we find:
$$ \#I_n \approx \#I_{n-1} \cdot 2 \cdot 10 / \ln(10^n) \approx 8.69 \cdot \#I_{n-1}/n. $$
Therefore, if $n > 9$, then we expect the growth of the sets $I_n$ to decline, eventually halting completely.

I again wrote some Python code to generate the sets:

```
import math as m
from sympy import *

I_old = [2,3,5,7]
I_new = set(I_old)
old_count = 4
new_count = 0

for i in range(1,36):
    for n in I_old:
        string = str(n)
        if len(string) != i:
            continue
        for d in range(10):
            d_string = str(d)
            for j in [0,len(string)]:
                new_string = string[:j] + d_string + string[j:]
                new_n = int(new_string)
                if isprime(new_n):
                    if i >= 28 and new_n not in I_new:
                        print("new prime:", new_n)
                    I_new.add(new_n)
    
    new_count = len(I_new) - len(I_old)
    if old_count != 0:
        ratio = new_count/old_count
    else:
        ratio = 0
    print(i, len(I_new), "growth ratio:", round(ratio, ndigits = 3))
    
    I_old = set(I_new)
    old_count = new_count
```

In about a minute it provides the following beautiful output!:

```
1 20 growth ratio: 4.0
2 90 growth ratio: 4.375
3 333 growth ratio: 3.471
4 971 growth ratio: 2.626
5 2421 growth ratio: 2.273
6 5240 growth ratio: 1.944
7 10191 growth ratio: 1.756
8 17820 growth ratio: 1.541
9 28497 growth ratio: 1.4
10 41764 growth ratio: 1.243
11 56946 growth ratio: 1.144
12 72869 growth ratio: 1.049
13 88665 growth ratio: 0.992
14 103034 growth ratio: 0.91
15 115581 growth ratio: 0.873
16 125872 growth ratio: 0.82
17 133811 growth ratio: 0.771
18 139514 growth ratio: 0.718
19 143425 growth ratio: 0.686
20 145984 growth ratio: 0.654
21 147579 growth ratio: 0.623
22 148499 growth ratio: 0.577
23 149060 growth ratio: 0.61
24 149381 growth ratio: 0.572
25 149548 growth ratio: 0.52
26 149620 growth ratio: 0.431
27 149657 growth ratio: 0.514
new prime: 83336721629457881953479913933
new prime: 54572189789429924839382391799
new prime: 39258915994516562635197199171
new prime: 34856966242312499439337339193
new prime: 99962668566642783154799373799
new prime: 38949534534819215283793999993
new prime: 62637863126462165676291379799
new prime: 32798215727562821638647937771
new prime: 62798215727562821638647937771
new prime: 93966242312359234717333999379
new prime: 95935129265429387433719199797
28 149668 growth ratio: 0.297
new prime: 662637863126462165676291379799
new prime: 627982157275628216386479377719
new prime: 833367216294578819534799139337
new prime: 699962668566642783154799373799
new prime: 545721897894299248393823917991
new prime: 939662423123592347173339993799
29 149674 growth ratio: 0.545
new prime: 6279821572756282163864793777199
new prime: 8939662423123592347173339993799
new prime: 8833367216294578819534799139337
30 149677 growth ratio: 0.5
31 149677 growth ratio: 0.0
32 149677 growth ratio: 0
33 149677 growth ratio: 0
34 149677 growth ratio: 0
35 149677 growth ratio: 0
```

This means that this variant of the Super Prime Set is finite and contains exactly $149677$ primes!
After $I_{29}$, no more primes will be found (the index is shifted by 1 in my code), and $8939662423123592347173339993799$ is the largest prime in the set.

We also see that the growth decline starts later than at index $9$, this can again be explained by the reasons given in the previous 'Python code' section.

Comment: I see that I made a small mistake in my code: the list will contain a lot of duplicate numbers, I need to remove those. Update: edited.